# How to do a Frequency count on tuples in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, nlp, tuples, named-entity-recognition

so i have a df

| Parsed | Clu |
| --- | --- |
| [('18', 'nummod'), ('years', 'nsubj'), ('of', 'prep'), ('age', 'pobj'), ('or', 'cc'), ('older', 'conj'), ('with', 'prep'), ('resectable', 'amod'), ('pancreatic', 'amod'), ('adenocarcinoma', 'pobj'), ('for', 'prep'), ('whom', 'pobj'), ('surgery', 'nsubjpass'), ('is', 'auxpass'), ('planned', 'relcl'), ('(', 'punct'), ('includes', 'ROOT'), ('borderline', 'compound'), ('resectable', 'dobj'), ('if', 'mark'), ('deemed', 'advcl'), ('appropriate', 'oprd'), ('by', 'agent'), ('surgical', 'amod'), ('investigators', 'pobj'), (')', 'punct'), ('or', 'cc'), ('has', 'aux'), ('occurred', 'conj'), ('within', 'prep'), ('the', 'det'), ('past', 'amod'), ('3', 'nummod'), ('years', 'pobj')] | 1 |
| [('HER2', 'nsubj'), ('must', 'aux'), ('negative', 'ccomp'), ('as', 'mark'), ('shown', 'advcl'), ('be', 'ROOT'), ('either', 'preconj'), ('0', 'attr'), ('or', 'cc'), ('1', 'conj'), ('+', 'conj'), ('by', 'prep'), ('immunohistochemistry', 'pobj'), ('(', 'punct'), ('if', 'mark'), ('2', 'dep'), ('+', 'advmod'), (',', 'punct'), ('in', 'prep'), ('situ', 'compound'), ('hybridization', 'compound'), ('method', 'pobj'), ('used', 'acl'), ('to', 'aux'), ('define', 'xcomp'), ('HER2', 'dobj'), (')', 'punct'), ('OR', 'pobj'), ('by', 'conj'), ('a', 'det'), ('HER2', 'pobj'), (':', 'punct'), ('17', 'nummod'), ('centromere', 'amod'), ('signal', 'pobj'), ('of', 'prep'), ('<', 'nmod'), ('2.0', 'pobj'), ('using', 'acl'), ('a', 'det'), ('standard', 'dobj'), ('in', 'prep'), ('situ', 'amod'), ('hybridization', 'compound'), ('method', 'pobj')] | 0 |
| [('Participants', 'nsubj'), ('who', 'nsubjpass'), ('are', 'auxpass'), ('planned', 'relcl'), ('to', 'aux'), ('undergo', 'xcomp'), ('neo', 'nmod'), ('-', 'amod'), ('adjuvant', 'amod'), ('chemotherapy', 'dobj'), ('are', 'ROOT'), ('eligible', 'acomp'), ('as', 'advmod'), ('long', 'advmod'), ('as', 'mark'), ('they', 'nsubj'), ('consent', 'advcl'), ('to', 'prep'), ('an', 'det'), ('additional', 'amod'), ('breast', 'compound'), ('biopsy', 'pobj'), ('following', 'prep'), ('the', 'det'), ('dietary', 'amod'), ('intervention', 'pobj'), ('immediately', 'advmod'), ('prior', 'advmod'), ('to', 'prep'), ('starting', 'pcomp'), ('chemotherapy', 'dobj')] | 0 |
| [('Uncontrolled', 'amod'), ('intercurrent', 'compound'), ('illness', 'ROOT'), ('including', 'prep'), (',', 'punct'), ('but', 'cc'), ('not', 'neg'), ('limited', 'conj'), ('to', 'prep'), (',', 'punct'), ('ongoing', 'amod'), ('or', 'cc'), ('active', 'conj'), ('infection', 'pobj'), (',', 'punct'), ('symptomatic', 'amod'), ('congestive', 'amod'), ('heart', 'compound'), ('failure', 'appos'), (',', 'punct'), ('unstable', 'amod'), ('angina', 'compound'), ('pectoris', 'appos'), (',', 'punct'), ('cardiac', 'amod'), ('arrhythmia', 'conj'), (',', 'punct'), ('or', 'cc'), ('psychiatric', 'amod'), ('illness', 'nmod'), ('/', 'punct'), ('social', 'amod'), ('situations', 'conj'), ('that', 'nsubj'), ('would', 'aux'), ('limit', 'relcl'), ('compliance', 'dobj'), ('with', 'prep'), ('study', 'compound'), ('requirements', 'pobj')] | 2 |

It was generated using dependency parse, the output is tuples.

I want to create a frequency count of each tuple per cluster.

lets say ('18', 'nummod')  appeared in 2 clusters then its frequency will be 2, just like we generate freq. count using Countvectorizer but with full tuples.

I can not find a way to do so, some methods that work only takes NER tags and plot freq. of that but i want freq. count of complete tuples, genertaed like this but with tuples instead of words. Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "A header" column are Python lists i.e. `df.dtypes: A header object Clu int64 dtype: object`, you can use `pd.DataFrame.explode()` and `pd.Series.value_counts()`.

```py
count_df = df.explode(column="A header").groupby("Clu")["A header"].value_counts().reset_index()
```

The output (`count_df.sample(n=5)`):

|  | Clu | A header | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52 | 0 | ('signal', 'pobj') | 1 |
| 104 | 2 | ('/', 'punct') | 1 |
| 83 | 1 | ('includes', 'ROOT') | 1 |
| 38 | 0 | ('+', 'advmod') | 1 |
| 56 | 0 | ('or', 'cc') | 1 |

Edit: I think I may have misread your question, and you want the number of clusters each tuple appears in. Similarly easy:

```py
count_df = df.explode(column="A header").groupby("A header")["Clu"].nunique()
```

Gives:

```
>>> count_df.sort_values(ascending=False)
A header
(or, cc)          3
((, punct)        2
(to, prep)        2
(if, mark)        2
(of, prep)        2
                 ..
(biopsy, pobj)    1
(be, ROOT)        1
(as, mark)        1
(as, advmod)      1
(years, pobj)     1
Name: Clu, Length: 124, dtype: int64
```